# Conditional Statement Won't Execute Slide Up in Javascript - Solved

Tags: javascript, if-statement, radio-button

I'm new to utilizing radio buttons and conditional statements is JavaScript/HTML, I would love to slide up fro two different div based on which radio button is selected.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--This is jQuery via Google CDN-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--Script to JavaScript-->
        <script src="select.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <!--This divide is for the creating/modifying a guestlist-->
            <div id="inviteType">
                <p>What Type of Invitations Will You be Sending?</p>
                <input type="radio" value="paperInvite" name="InviteType" id="paperInvite">
                <label for="paperInvite">Paper + Electronic Invitations</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" value="elecInvite" name="InviteType" id="elecInvite">
                <label for="elecInvite">Electronic Invitations</label>
                <br>
                <button id="submitInvite">Submit</button>

            </div>
        <div id="paper">
                <form id="paperGuest">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                    <label for="guestPhone">Guest Phonenumber</label>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="+0(123)345-6789" id="guestPhone">
                    <!--This section of code is for the address lines-->
                    <label for="guestAddress">Please Enter Guest Address</label>
                    <textarea id="guestAddress"  required></textarea>
                    <div id="#guestAddPopUp">
                        You can either copy and paste from your contacts, or you may enter the address within this format. <br>
                        1234 S. Buttermore Ave. Apt. 16 <br>
                        Plainsville, AL 70832 &#10 <br>
                        (Country, if if applicable)
                    </div>
                    <label for="additionalGuest">Additional Guests</label>
                    <select class="additionalGuest" name="additionalGuests">
                        <option value="none">None</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                    <button id="paperSubmit">Submit</button>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div id="electronic">
            <form id="elecGuest">
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                <label for="guestPhone">Guest Phonenumber</label>
                <input type="tel" placeholder="+0(123)345-6789" id="guestPhone">
                <label for="guestEmail">Guest Email</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="person123@mail.com">
                <label for="additionalGuest">Additional Guests</label>
                 <select class="additionalGuest" name="additionalGuests">
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
                <button id="elecSubmit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    $("#paper").hide();
    $("#electronic").hide();
 
     var inviteType = document.getElementById("submitInvite");
     inviteType.addEventListener("click", function() { 
            let InviteType = $('input[name="InviteType"]:checked').val();
            document.body.style.color = "#214010";
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#CAE6AC";
            if (InviteType = "paperInvite") {
                $("#ModCreGuest").slideUp(2700);
                $("#paper").slideDown(3300);  
                /*this section of code helps to add the different guests with paper invitations to the index*/
                var paperSubmit = document.getElementById("paperSubmit");
                paperSubmit.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#ModCreGuest").slideUp(2700);
                $("#electronic").slideDown(3300);

            }
        });
    });
```

Is there a problem with my conditional statement or is there a problem with selecting my radio button? Thank you.

Comment: Is the page being submitted and reloaded from the server before you get a chance to see the results of calling slideup/slidedown methods take effect? Try putting a `console.log ("last loaded: ", Date))` somewhere in top level code if you want to see when the page was last loaded.

Comment: I double checked at the top level of my code and it looks like the slideup/slidedown is taking effect after the page is reloaded from the server. I guess now I'm wondering why the conditional statement won't switch from one div class to another.

Comment: Short answer - it doesn't switch because the  click handler is not executed after the page reloads. User input in forms that are not submitted may also get wiped out. I suggest looking into preventing submit events until all user input is complete or use session storage to save user input across reloads.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I changed the submit to a button, the updated code is above in the post. Thanks again!